# $\binom{z}{n}$ converges to $0$ if and only if $\Re z >-1$

Tags: complex-analysis

$\binom{z}{n} = \frac{z\cdot (z-1) \cdot \ldots\cdot(z-n+1)}{n!}$ and $z\in\mathbb{C}$ is a complex number. 
Please, can you help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you asking for
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \binom{n}{z} = 0 \qquad \text{iff } \Re z > -1$$
If so, please modify the question and add MathJax ($)

Comment: not (n choose z) but (z choose n). I have edited.

Comment: Okay, And how about the limit?

Comment: yes you are right. we should consider a sequence and find the limit of the sequence as n goes to infinity